# Selecting .not(this) not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a few select lists that all have the same contents. What I want is when an option is selected in one, it will be disabled in the others.

```
<div class="social-option">
    <select>
        <option selected="selected" value="facebook">facebook</option>
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="twitter">twitter</option><!-- If I select this -->
        <option value="linkedin">linkedin</option>
        <option value="instagram">instagram</option>
        <option value="flickr">flickr</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="social-option">
    <select>
        <option selected="selected" value="facebook">facebook</option>
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="twitter">twitter</option><!-- then this is disabled -->
        <option value="linkedin">linkedin</option>
        <option value="instagram">instagram</option>
        <option value="flickr">flickr</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="social-option">
    <select>
        <option selected="selected" value="facebook">facebook</option>
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="twitter">twitter</option><!-- and this also is disabled -->
        <option value="linkedin">linkedin</option>
        <option value="instagram">instagram</option>
        <option value="flickr">flickr</option>
    </select>
</div>​
```

using this:

```
$('.social-option select').on('change', function () {

    var newSelected = $('option:selected', this).val();
    var newSelectedSiblings = $('.social-option select').find("option[value=" + newSelected + "]");

    newSelectedSiblings.not(this).each(function() { //here is the .not selector that doesn't work
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

​Any ideas why?

Also, why doen't this line work when I replace the selector with `this`:

```
var newSelectedSiblings = $('.social-option select').find("option[value=" + newSelected + "]");
```

like this:

```
var newSelectedSiblings = $(this).find("option[value=" + newSelected + "]");
```

since the `change` selector is the same: `$('.social-option select').on('change'...`

http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/4BBcZ/5/

**Update**

I've found a solutions to the first question:
instead

```
newSelectedSiblings.not(this)
```

I used:

```
newSelectedSiblings.not('option:selected', this)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `siblings()` function. It does what you think it does:

```
$(this).siblings().each(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

The `not()` function doesn't work because jQuery is strange when it comes to comparisons:

```
$(this) == $(this) // Returns false
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is confusing the `select` tag and the `option` tag.

`newSelectedSiblings` finds an option tag, but `this` in the callback is the select tag.

So `not` does nothing.

I would try to fix your code since it's seems far too complex, but I can't figure out what you are trying to do.

If you disable all the other selects, except the selected one, then how will anyone ever pick them?

Please clarify what you mean by "all sibling elements but the clicked one here" - select tags don't have a "clicked" attribute - so what do you mean by that?

Or are you trying to select all the option tags except the selected one? What for?

```
$('.social-option select').on('change', function () {
  $('.social-option select').not(this).find('option[name="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //make sure none of the options have a " in the value
}
```

Note: There is no mention of un-disabling an option if you change your selection. Doing so might be complicated since you have no record of what it was.

Comment: Thanx, I am trying to disable the selected option in other lists, if I select 'facebook' in one, I won't be able to select it in the others (added a jsfiddle)

Comment: Also, why is it then replacing `$('.social-option select')` inside the `change function` with `$(this)` doesn't work? from what you said it is suppose to..

Comment: @IlyaD BTW the function to set the disabled attribute is completely unnecessary - jQuery will apply such a function automatically to all the elements.

Comment: I've updated my question (look at the top). I don't understand why it's not necessary, what exactly is not necessary?

Comment: @IlyaD The `each()` function/loop is not necessary. Just do `newSelectedSiblings.not(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')` - you don't need to wrap it in a loop. But in any case, I'm pretty sure the code I wrote for you will do what you are asking.